# When can an affine functional on the dual be represented as an element of a Banach space?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, measure-theory, banach-spaces, geometric-measure-theory

In [*Measures Which Agree on Balls*](https://www.mscand.dk/article/download/11610/9626) by Hoffmann-Jørgenson, we are given a functional $\varphi: T(x_0)\to (-\infty, \infty]$, which is a lower semicontinuous, affine, Baire function on a subspace $T(x_0)$ of $E^*$ (the dual of a Banach space $E$) This subspace is defined as $$T(x_0):= \{x^* \in E^*: \|x^*\| \leq 1 \text{ and } \langle x^*,x_0 \rangle=1 \}$$ where $x_0\in E$ and $\|x_0\|=1$. Then, given this $\varphi$, we let $A$ be the set of affine functions $\psi$ such that

1. $\psi\left(x^*\right)<\varphi\left(x^*\right), \quad \forall x^* \in T\left(x_0\right),
   $ and
2. $\psi$ is the restriction of a $w^*$-continuous affine function defined on all of $E^*$.

It is claimed on page 321 that given any $\varphi_n \in A$ there exists a $y_n \in E$ such that $\varphi_n(x^*)=x^*(y_n)$ for all $x^* \in T(x_0)$. Why is this? It is not clear that $\varphi_n$ is even a linear functional on $E^*$, nor is it assumed that $E$ is reflexive. Am I missing something? The only justification in the paper for this conclusion is that $\varphi_n \in A$.

Comment: Elements of $A$ are restrictions of weak-star continuous affine functions $E^* \to {\bf R}$; surely such functions on $E^\ast$ are just given by $x^*\mapsto x^\ast(y)+c$ for some $y\in E^\ast$ and some $c\in {\bf R}$. Have I overlooked a subtlety?

Comment: @YemonChoi I agree with everything you've said, but I don't see why that implies that such a function $\phi_n(x^*)$ can be represented as $x^*(y_n)$. Wouldn't that necessitate that $c=0$, and, further, that the space be reflexive?

Comment: It looks an innocent typo. Hoffmann-Jørgenson missed the constant term and Yemon wrote $y\in E^*$ instead of $y \in E$.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA Sorry to be obtuse, but I think I understand this even less than I thought. Why are these functions necessarily of that form without the assumption that $E$ is reflexive? How does the assumption of being a weak-star continuous affine function from the whole dual get us there? I would really appreciate if you spelled this out explicitly.

Comment: An weak$^\ast$-continuous linear functional on $E^*$ is given by an element in $E$.